# CSS width 100% в firefox

Tags: css

Уважаемые коллеги, объясните, пожалуйста нюанс с width 100% в firefox?
Почему в Chrome поля ввода такие, как нужно, а в firefox они получаются перерастянуты

```
    element.style {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
<style>
.jss220 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
<style>
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="text" i] {
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(195, 195, 195));
    border-image: initial;
}
<style>
body {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: 0.01071em;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
<style>
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
<style>
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
<style>
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
```

Comment: Пример в студию... Нет такого бага в браузере, это сопутствующие стили могут всё портить

Comment: @InDevX есть только devtools. Добавил

Comment: @GrossmasteR не имея [mcve] говорить будет не о чем